# Cannot connect to remote zookeeper

Tags: ubuntu, networking, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

I'm trying to set up a kafka cluster with a single zookeeper instance that is running on a different machine than the kafka servers.

I'm able to connect to my ZooKeeper instance from the same machine (by creating a kafka server on that machine), but I'm not able to connect other kafka servers from machines that are in the local network.

All servers are running in a private cloud where all ports are open by default. I'm able to ping and telnet to the machine, but I can't seem to reach the ZooKeeper instance:

```
# On the ZooKeeper machine
> telnet 10.155.208.82 2181
Trying 10.155.208.82...
Connected to 10.155.208.82.

# On any other machine
> telnet 10.155.208.82 22
Trying 10.155.208.82...
Connected to 10.155.208.82.

> telnet 10.155.208.82 2181
Trying 10.155.208.82...
# Nothing happens ...
```

Kafka is erroring out after the timeout to connect to the ZooKeeper is exceeded:

`[2015-12-28 18:52:21,632] INFO Initiating client connection, connectString=10.155.208.82:2181 sessionTimeout=6000 watcher=org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient@43ee72e6 (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2015-12-28 18:52:21,645] INFO Opening socket connection to server 10.155.208.82/10.155.208.82:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error) (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[2015-12-28 18:52:21,650] INFO Waiting for keeper state SyncConnected (org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient)
[2015-12-28 18:52:27,651] INFO Terminate ZkClient event thread. (org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkEventThread)
[2015-12-28 18:52:27,758] INFO Session: 0x0 closed (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2015-12-28 18:52:27,759] INFO EventThread shut down (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[2015-12-28 18:52:27,760] FATAL Fatal error during KafkaServer startup. Prepare to shutdown (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
org.I0Itec.zkclient.exception.ZkTimeoutException: Unable to connect to zookeeper server within timeout: 6000
    at org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient.connect(ZkClient.java:1223)
    at org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient.<init>(ZkClient.java:155)
    at org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient.<init>(ZkClient.java:129)
    at kafka.utils.ZkUtils$.createZkClientAndConnection(ZkUtils.scala:89)
    at kafka.utils.ZkUtils$.apply(ZkUtils.scala:71)
    at kafka.server.KafkaServer.initZk(KafkaServer.scala:278)
    at kafka.server.KafkaServer.startup(KafkaServer.scala:168)
    at kafka.server.KafkaServerStartable.startup(KafkaServerStartable.scala:37)
    at kafka.Kafka$.main(Kafka.scala:67)
    at kafka.Kafka.main(Kafka.scala)
[2015-12-28 18:52:27,764] INFO shutting down (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
[2015-12-28 18:52:27,770] INFO shut down completed (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
[2015-12-28 18:52:27,771] FATAL Fatal error during KafkaServerStartable startup. Prepare to shutdown (kafka.server.KafkaServerStartable)`

What am I doing wrong? If it helps, the virtual machines do not have any hostnames assigned to them within the private cloud.